# What is a catalog of images and their description called

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests

I am creating a game in which I want to create a "What is what section", it is basically going to be a list of items containing an image with its name per item (Example image of the lead character with his name, image of a magical cube with its name etc etc).

What should such a section be called?

Example:

> Confused knowing what is what? Visit the **____** section."

I need a word for the blank space.

Comment: Maybe "*Character profile* section"? Note that *catalog*, itself, has meant "an listing of inventory with pictures and associated descriptions" since [at least 1894](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mail_order#Sears).

Comment: I think it's common for games to call this an encyclopedia.

Comment: *Catalog* works, but in your context it might evoke an impression of a place where you are selling other products. I would go with *gallery*, which evoke the idea that everything is on display there.

Comment: Visit the *Hall of Records*

Comment: It's just the Image Gallery -- where the images have captions and text descriptions as well. We could say "To know What is What, Visit the Image Gallery **for Descriptions** ."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A simple answer would be to call it the "reference section".

The Oxford English dictionary gives as one of the definitions of "reference":

"direction to a book, passage, etc., where information may be found"

Answer (score 1):

If you are truly just having an image and its name (no further sentences of explanation), then that is a *key*. [The online *Oxford English Dictionary* definition is:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/key)

> An explanatory list of symbols used in a map, table, etc.

If you will describe each thing, then you might call this a [*glossary*.](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/glossary)

Comment: Reference, please.

Answer (score 1):

You might try something along the lines of "pictorial lexicon".  [Here's an example](http://capl.washjeff.edu) of one.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

The part of a document that defines specialized terms is a *glossary*.

Since your glossary uses images, it is a *visual glossary*. You can leave out the word "section" from your example, because glossary already implies that meaning.